# Argument of type 'AbstractHttpAdapter<any, any, any>' exception configuring all-exceptions filter

Tags: exception, filter, nestjs

I want to configure all-exceptions filter as per the nestjs documentation but currently getting the error below. Someone help

Argument of type 'AbstractHttpAdapter<any, any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HttpAdapterHost<AbstractHttpAdapter<any, any, any>>'.
Property 'httpAdapter' is missing in type 'AbstractHttpAdapter<any, any, any>' but required in type 'HttpAdapterHost<AbstractHttpAdapter<any, any, any>>'.

**Exception filter class**

```js
    import {
        ExceptionFilter,
        Catch,
        ArgumentsHost,
        HttpException,
        HttpStatus,
      } from '@nestjs/common';
      import { HttpAdapterHost } from '@nestjs/core';
      
      @Catch()
      export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
        constructor(private readonly httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {}
      
        catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
          // In certain situations `httpAdapter` might not be available in the
          // constructor method, thus we should resolve it here.
          const { httpAdapter } = this.httpAdapterHost;
      
          const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
      
          const httpStatus =
            exception instanceof HttpException
              ? exception.getStatus()
              : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
      
          const responseBody = {
            statusCode: httpStatus,
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
            path: httpAdapter.getRequestUrl(ctx.getRequest()),
          };
      
          httpAdapter.reply(ctx.getResponse(), responseBody, httpStatus);
        }
      }
```

**main.ts file**

[image: The image of where am using the filter class]

Comment: Please provide the code of your exception filter class and where you apply it so that the community would be able to advise.

Comment: Hello @DimiVi, I have updated that, kindly check it out. Thanks for helping

Comment: Check out `package.json` and ensure both `@nestjs/core` and `@nestjs/common` have the same version. I suppose your issue may be caused by a version mismatch.

Comment: These is it as per my package.json "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",

Comment: Instead of injecting `HttpAdapter` reference, try using `APP_FILTER` token as shown here: https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#binding-filters

Answer (score 3):

use

```
const httpAdapter = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);
```

instead of

```
const { httpAdapter } = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You've told Typescript that the `AllExceptionsFilter` should take in an `HttpAdapterHost`, and you get an `HttpAdapterHost` from the `app` instace via `app.get(HttpAdapterHost)` in your `main.ts`, but then you pass `HttpAdapterHost#httpAdapter` to `AllExceptionsFilter` instead of passing `HttpAdapterHost`. Typescript is properly warning you that what you are passing, and what you've said the filter should take in on construction are not the same property